# How to consume wcf service with callback in web?

Tags: php, wcf, wsdualhttpbinding

I have a project that requires PHP to connect into WCF self host. The structure was, I have a selfhost wcf with tcp and WSDualHttpBinding protocols. I've used PHP SOAP version 1 and wcf has EnvelopVersion Soap12. I tried to test PHP code below but unfortunately couldn't make it work. I try to type the Url in my browser "http://...:8009/Service/Service/?wsdl" to test if my WCF was up and xml was appeared so it means wcf is up and running. Is it possible to notify web client if I have callback in the my self host service? Thanks in advance.

```
    <?php

try
{
    $client = new SoapClient('http://...:8009/Service/Service/?wsdl',
    array(
                'location' => 'http://...:8009/Service/Service/',
                'trace' => true,
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY
        )); 
        .
        .
        .

} catch ( Exception $e )
{
    echo "Error:".$e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to be any more vague? :)  Seriously - can you elaborate on what you're trying or want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry @Tim, I already revised my question hope that it is more clear.

Comment: If you're constrained to using SOAP 1.1 (I'm not familiar with PHP), then you may have to go with BasicHttpBinding (which is 1.1).  I'm not confident that you'll be able to use WsDualHttpBinding with a non-.NET client, but others may have a way to do that.

Comment: Okay Tim thanks,Any way do you have any idea how to implement callback or notification in asp once I subscribe in my self host service?

Comment: If you mean an ASP.NET application that has subscribed to your service, take a look at [Implementing Callback using WCF](http://geekswithblogs.net/ramkinkarpandey/archive/2009/10/24/implementing-callback-using-wcf.aspx).  Also check Google, as there are tons of examples on how to do this.

Comment: I already done implementing callback in my desktop application using c# console app client. What I didn't know was how to implement callback once the client is using the web browser. I already search in google but no luck... any thanks for reply.